# Microsoft post_logout_redirect_uri Not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I m trying to logout Microsoft Account Like:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000.

But It's not redirecting to redirect Url.It's showing : [image]

Thank

Comment: I am having this problem right now too (although mine is an APS.Net MVC app) and if you google it there are 100s of reported problems of the same.... thing is, if you hit BACK, it hasn't logged you out either (well, not from what I cansee)

Answer (score 1):

You should get redirected unless the post_logout_redirect_uri is not [registered as a reply_url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request) or the user is already logged out.

Comment: I've already added this to my reply url list and it still doesnt redirect

Comment: Please detail the app registration configuration (reply url and types, audience, etc) and authentication flow (authorization, pkce, implicit) and user accounts affected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem. I found that the post logout redirection doens't work for root accounts of the tenant, that is my personal account, which created Azure subscription. But it works for new accounts I created inside of my subscription.

Answer (score -1):

Its known bug for login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout, you can do nothing about it.